# How is the DataContext of a ControlTemplate set?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, datatemplate, controltemplate

I am setting the ControlTemplate in a Tile control (in the Telerik TileList).  It looks something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:Tile}">
    <Border>

        <!-- Some Content that binds to DP on the view models -->

            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />

    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Elsewhere:

```
<telerik:RadTileList ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentViewModels}">
```

And I have DataTemplates defined for the items that would be presented within the Tile's ContentPresenter.  The trouble I have is that, when a ComponentViewModel is added to the target of the ItemsSource (ComponentViewModel ObservableCollection) a new Tile appears but it's DataContext is the RadTileList's ViewModel and not the individual component's ViewModel.

Am I missing something regarding the setting of the DataContext in a ControlTemplate?

Comment: Sounds like a telerik bug to me. Following the `ItemsControl` philosophy of WPF the `ItemContainers` (`Tiles` in this case) should have their datacontext set to the corresponding item in the `ItemsSource` collection. Exactly the same way as any other `ItemsControl`-based UI element does.

Comment: I've opened a ticket with Telerik.  I hope that is not it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to do it.  I needed to do TemplateBinding for the ContentTemplate and Content properties.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:Tile}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

To bind to a property on the Presenter or ViewModel attached to the DataContext on the parent view or control from inside a DataTemplate you have to use the RelativeSource property with the value “FindAncestor” and the type of the control with the DataContext you are looking for.

The most common mistake I’ve seen using this, is people forgetting to use the {x:Type yourControlType} markup extension for the AcestorType property and using “AncestorType=yourControlType” instead.

Here is an example:

```
Width="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

where “SomeProperty” is a property on the Presenter or ViewModel that follows the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern.

Width is the property of the control inside the the ControlTemplate